# Cannot resolve symbols setAdapter and AttachToListView in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was attaching the list view to FAB, but Android Studio is showing the following error:

> cannot resolve symbol at setAdapter and AttachToListView methods

I tried rebuilding and closing and reopening the project.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


String[] values = new String[]{"Change message", "Change picture"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);


FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.AttachToListView(listView);
}
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/androidparty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/birthday_message"
    android:text="Many many happy returns of the day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/from_text"
    android:text="From, "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>
<com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/from_text"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_content_new"
    app:fab_colorNormal="#424242"
    android:textAllCaps="true"/>
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Move all of that inside of a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written all the code outside `onCreate()`. As codeMagic said, move all your code as shown below

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] values = new String[]{"Change message", "Change picture"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.AttachToListView(listView);
    }   
}
```